# Add joystick and touch controls for Android to 3D character on Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Could anyone tell me how I could make a 3D character move using a mobile joystick? I'm developing for Android on Unity and this one part I'm stuck on, basically I want to be able to move the character with a joystick and then be able to rotate through touching the screen.

Answer (score 0):

For the plugged joystick, it's basically like any PC joystick. So you just have to use the old fashioned `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")` and `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` method. Be sure to map those in *input from all joysticks* in your *Project preference > Inputs*.
[Official doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html)

As for the touch, it also works easily with *Input.GetTouch(0).position*
[Official doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html)

You may also want to raycast the touch tap in order to get the world-scale position of the position you are touching:

```
private static Vector3 GetPositionFromScreenPosition(Vector3 screenPosition)
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(screenPosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
    {
        return hit.point;
    }

    return Vector3.zero;
}
```

Both works well on the same *Update()* or *FixedUpdate()* method.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current code:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class PlayerMover : MonoBehaviour {
    public Joystick joystick;
    public float characterSpeed = 175f;
    public float turnSpeed = 10f;

    void Start() {

        joystick = FindObjectOfType<Joystick>();

    }
    void Update() {

      var rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
      rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(joystick.Horizontal * characterSpeed, rigidbody.velocity.y, joystick.Vertical * characterSpeed);
      float turn = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * turnSpeed;
            transform.Rotate(0, turn * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

      UpdateAnimator();

    }
    private void UpdateAnimator() {

      Vector3 velocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;
      Vector3 localVelocity = transform.InverseTransformDirection(velocity);
      float speed = localVelocity.z;
      GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("movementSpeed", speed);

    }

}
```